# Why do these NSView swift subclesses allow initialisation to run twice

Tags: swift, nsview

In the Swift subclasses below, when `ChildView(dummy: NSObject())` is called, two different designated initializers for ParentView will be invoked, and the `myLayer` ivar of `ParentView` will be initialized twice.

Not that this will not happen in a Playground - that will correctly report that `error: MyPlayground.playground:5:31: error: must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'NSView'`

However, in an Xcode project (e.g. a Command Line Tool), this will compile and run fine.

I understand a lot of what's going on, and how to prevent this problem. But I'd love to understand why the compiler is not erroring, or at least warning me about this code (and preventing the double initialisation)

This code compiles cleanly under Swift 4.2, and in the debugger, I can see exactly what's happening:

When `ChildView(dummy:)` is called, it invokes `ParentView(dummy:)`

That's a designated initialiser, do the ParentView ivars are also initialised (`myLayer`)

Then `ParentView(dummy:)` calls `super.init()`, which is `NSView.init()`

The implementation of NSView.init() calls `initWithFrame`, so `ChildView.init(frame:)` gets invoked, and invokes `ParentView.init(frame:)`. That's also a designated initialiser, so
`myLayer` gets initialised a second time.

To demonstrate this, given the classes below, invoke

`let _ = ChildView(dummy: NSObject)`

`>>>> creating layer` will get printed twice.

The way to avoid this would be to have `ParentView(dummy:)` call `super.init(frame:)`, and then the problem goes away.

My question is really, how could this ever happen in the first place?

```
import Cocoa

class ParentView: NSView {
    private var myLayer: CALayer = {
        print(">>>> creating layer")
        return CALayer()
    }()

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) { super.init(frame: frameRect) }
    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: decoder) }
    init(dummy: AnyObject?) { self.init() }
}

class ChildView: ParentView {
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) { super.init(frame: frameRect) }
    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: decoder) }
    override init(dummy: AnyObject?) { super.init(dummy: dummy) }
}
```

This *should* generate a compile time error, as it does in a Playground.

I can't seem to construct a similar non-NSView class hierarchy that gives the same behaviour. No matter how I tweak the hierarchy, constructors, etc., Swift always gives compiler errors when I try to this with new objects (even when I mix Objective-C and Swift, to be analagous to NSView.

I can't find any public declaration for NSView.init() either, although I can see it executing in the debugger.

Comment: `NSView.init()` is defined in `Objective C` code, and `Objective C` `init` can do whatever it wants, absolutely anything, it may even return prepared instance instead of initializing currently allocated; and even more: this prepared instance can be of different type, like completely different type, with non-matching interface and memory layout. And, of course it call call any other functions/send messages in any order and sequence.

Comment: It is true that NSView.init() can do "whatever it wants". However, it is not marked as a designated initializer, and the Swift initialisation rules (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) state that "A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass." So ... the above code is not actually legal swift. However it does compile.